# TextView Weight via Java code

Tags: java, android

I have this code in xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rankLVs"
    android:text="Rank"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#2980b9"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

I tried to make the same code but this time via java, with this code:

```
rank.setText(""+json.getInt("ranking"));
rank.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_shape));
rank.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
rank.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2980b9"));
rank.setPadding(0,dpAsPixels,0,0);
rank.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
rank.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

The result was this: 
[image]

The top row is made with xml, that means the code I wrote in java disappeared. When I put

```
rank.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

in comment the result is: 
 [image]

Which is really weird.
**How can I make it look normal?**

Comment: where do you want to put it?

Comment: Can you post your complete layout xml?